# Usar o login do wordpress em outro site

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

Hoje tenho um site feito em Joomla, onde o usuário faz login, e se estiver em determinado grupo, consegue acessar uma área restrita, site php desenvolvido internamente. Este site está em um diretório no mesmo servidor do joomla.

Pretendo migrar para o Wordpress, e busco um plugin, ou outra forma de manter este mecanismo de permissão ao site desenvolvido pela empresa, usando o controle de acesso do próprio wordpress.

- Somente usuários logados podem acessar a área restrita;
- A aparência da área restrita não precisa ser a mesma do site wordpress;

Comment: Voce quer usar o controle de acesso do WP nesse outro site que esta em joomla? Se for isso acho que esse plugin pode funcionar [JSON API Auth](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth) confesso que nunca precisei fazer isso, entao nao sei exatamente se esse plugin resolve tudo.

Comment: Não... o que preciso é que o site feito em php, que é um painel administrativo, fique acessível apenas para usuários que fizeram login no wordpress. O Joomla vai cair fora na verdade.

Comment: Mesmo assim acho que esse plugin que passei parece ser uma boa saida, por que voce vai precisar entre outras coisas do "role" do usuario no WP em seu site, para exibir o conteudo correto do painel certo? Aparentemente essa JSON API Auth vai te dar essas informações.

Comment: Vou testar as duas opções. E adiciono os resultados aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um filtro `login_redirect` é usado para alterar o local redirecionado após fazer o login. Este poderia ser o local definido pelo parâmetro "redirect_to" enviadas para a página de login. Aí nas suas páginas você poderia usar uma função para redirecionar caso não tenha feito login. Este exemplo redireciona administradores para o painel e outros usuários para a página inicial.

```
<?php auth_redirect(); ?>
```

#### Exemplo

Exigir que um usuário faça o login, a fim de visualizar uma página restrita com [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/):

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
   auth_redirect();
}
```

Dê uma lida aqui no [Function Reference/auth redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect).

Comment: Ate funciona, mas o complicado vai ser ele chamar a funcao `is_user_logged_in()` que so existe no WP dentro do painel que ele ja tem. Funciona muito bem dentro de um plugin ou tema do WP.

Comment: Mas ai você pode usar `require_once` para impotar o arquivos de funções do seu plugin, manja?

Comment: Vou testar as duas opções. E adiciono os resultados aqui.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @CleidimarViana preciso testar melhor. Tive que adicionar alguns plugins para poder adicionar links para um projeto externo. O diretório painel está no mesmo nível do root do wordpress. Acredito que consiga fazer os imports necessários. Assim que eu testar tudo posto os resultados e valido a resposta.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Boa Sorte!

Comment: @CleidimarViana a forma que você postou resolve o problema, você pode colocar mais informações de como fazer. Tipo, em qual diretório é mais correto eu colocar a pasta do site do PHP. Ou outra alternativa usando um plugin, tipo o Advanced Access Manager por exemplo.